Versioning convention
I have some trouble understanding the rationale about polkadot/substrate versioning.
I tried to add 'Utility' pallet to a my solo chain and it didn't match the runtime version. To my surprise, the crate version for 'frame-support' is 37.0.0 (38 is the latest on crate.io) but in source code I noticed that the master frame-support pallet Cargo tells it is by now at version 28.0.0
Not only this. Then I went to releases on polkadot sdk and it also does not make sense to me (of course it is something I am missing). There is a couple of versioning convention something along the lines 1.19 (old versioning) and stable2409-2 (which I believe is the new versioning convention).
I can infere that we are talking about a stable release for sep 2024 (dic 2024 is still release candidate)
This is hard for me to make my mind around this and I haven't found anything telling whats the convention nor a compatibility matrix.
Is there a "best practice" to navigate between releases/component versions?
Thanks in advance!

Always follow the tag if you want to use the crates.io dependencies.
Currently, the latest one is https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/tree/polkadot-stable2409.
The crates.io version is different from the master. Because they always do a "apply plan" job in the tag release.
